# Shifting a table by deleting rows and columns

Tags: excel, vba, cells

I have a table populated by random numbers and I would like to delete x number of columns from the left of the table, x number of rows from the bottom of the table and move the remaining values to the bottom left corner.

```
Public Sub shiftrandom()
Dim Difference As integer
Difference = 5
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To Difference
    Range("B2:B20").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("B20:N20").Delete Shift:=xlDown
Next i

End Sub
```

Here B2:B20 is first column and B20:N20 is the last row. This is a 13x19 table.

the `Range("B2:B20").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft` works fine by its own, it shifts all the remaining values to the left by the correct number of columns, but the shift down line returns an

> out of bounds error.

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `xlUp` for the row?

Comment: Could you show some sample data and expected outcome? And is Delete as xlUp not ok?

Comment: xlUp deletes the bottom row  but only the bottom row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don’t loop

```
Public Sub shiftrandom()
    Dim Difference As Long
    Difference = 5
    With Range("B2:N20")
        .Resize(,Difference).Delete
        .Rows(.Rows.Count - Difference + 1).Resize(Difference).Delete 
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This deletes all the correct columns and rows and does it far more efficiently than looping. The data ends up in the top left though. Do you know how I would define the new range for the remaining data so I could shift it down the right number of positions?

Comment: I've managed to move it down by selecting the range and pasting at the appropriate place, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Excel does not shift `Down` or `Right` when deleting.

Only `Left` or `Up` are possible:

**XlShift** - Used only with Range objects. Specifies how to shift cells to replace deleted cells. Can be one of the following XlDeleteShiftDirection constants: `xlShiftToLeft` or `xlShiftUp` . If this argument is omitted, Microsoft Excel decides based on the shape of the range.

[MSDN - Delete Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-delete-method-excel)

[image]